# Java - read font characters from ttf file

Tags: java, fonts

For android app I'm working right now i have to test that font file supplies all needed characters. Hoverwer I can have a lot ttf files, so i wanted to check every.

But heres my problem: How to read font chars in UTF-8 and iterate through them?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the way it worked for me was that a friend of mine prepared svg file with font and we could generate data with javascript from that file.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the [sfntly](https://code.google.com/p/sfntly/) library

This has been used in [Android Font Creator](https://code.google.com/p/fontcreator/) project

I was able to print glyph ids and names using the [test program](https://sfntly.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/src/com/google/typography/font/sfntly/sample/sfntdump/SfntDump.java) on a desktop app. Should work on Android as well.

Comment: Isn't there any other way? TTF files does not contain such information in its description?